# Question about Neeyat (Intent) in Islam

Tags: sharia

I really liked the concept of Neeyat (Intent) as the core essence of what Islam preaches. Having said that, why does we see terrorists killing people for some cause? Isnt it against the good intent which Islam preaches?

Does Islam allow people who terrorize others?

I really want to know the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Islam, [actions are judged by their intentions](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1), as you rightly pointed out. However, for an action to be accepted by God, in addition to intention, that action must be permissible and performed according to the *shari`ah*.

Terrorists killing innocent civilians goes against both counts - the intention is wrong (it is a geopolitical motivation and intention, it is not for Allah) and the method is wrong as well (killing innocents is among the harshest prohibitions in Islam).

Comment: And they are not at all following sayings of islam, and not even following islamic rules , If you see the history of islam no one has ever killed any child, women's and elderly even if they found in the while waged wars.